# What is the Java equivalent of Debugger.Launch()?

Tags: java, .net, debugging

What is the Java equivalent of [Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent to this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still valid for 1.4+ but there is
[jdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdb.html).

There is also [com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/connect/AttachingConnector.html).